# Where can I find instruction booklets?

Tags: instructions

Is there any place where scans or PDFs of instruction booklets can be downloaded?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, from [themselves](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/), for sets from 2002 onwards.

[D-N-D Bricks](https://web.archive.org/web/20110526040823/http://www.dndbricks.com:80/legobuildinginstructions.htm)(archived) use to have a lot of older sets' instructions.
[List of archived instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.dndbricks.com:80/pdf/*).

Answer (score 18):

These sites are absolutely marvellous:

- [Let's Build It Again](http://letsbuilditagain.com/) - this has user submissions too
- [BrickFactory](http://www.brickfactory.info/) - if you can't find it on here, then it can't exist
- [WorldBricks](http://www.worldbricks.com/) - looks to be another cracking resource

(Having just spent some time looking through these, I just don't know why I hadn't tried looking for this stuff before.)

Answer (score 7):

If you have an Android device, the app [Lego Scans](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mk.legoscans2&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tay5sZWdvc2NhbnMyIl0) is also very convenient.

> Ever lost a LEGO® scan or you maybe want to take a trip down memory lane?
>   This app enables you to browse through 4000 LEGO® scans by box number or by theme.
>   You can choose to save the scan image files to your SD card for offline viewing! This also enables you to view the scan in your favorite image app!

Comment: This app was removed from the Play Store some years ago.

Answer (score 6):

The following sites all have instructions:

- [Lego](http://us.service.lego.com/en-GB/BuildingInstructions/default.aspx) (2002 onwards)
- [The Brick Factory](http://www.brickfactory.info/)
- [D-N-D Bricks](http://dndbricks.com/legobuildinginstructions.htm)
- [World Bricks](http://www.worldbricks.com/)
- [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/scans/?ct=1)
- [Cubiculus](http://www.cubiculus.com/building-instruction.html) - not scans, but recreations of instructions from many official sets

Answer (score 4):

[Peeron](http://www.peeron.com) also has a bunch of instructions for sets over 5 years old.  In addition, it has a parts breakdown of most sets Lego has produced.

Answer (score 1):

Lego.com. Just hope you have the box or some information. [Lego.com Support- Set Instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions)

Comment: Welcome to LEGO Answers.  This seems somewhat redundant to the other answers.  Can you add something to make this more helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Besides being a great LEGO community website, [Brickset](http://www.brickset.com) has even different versions of almost every set imaginable.