# Bluetooth will not connect Error code: -142016

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, bluetooth

NXT 2.0 Error code: -142016

The Bluetooth does connect. I am not having these issues with any of my other Bluetooth devices running off of the same dongle.

Where do I find the meaning of any other error codes that I may encounter for the NXT?

Comment: Are you running Win7 64bits?

Comment: Or just Windows 7 - there are some [compatibility issues](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1079/56) with some of the software and Windows 7.

Comment: You say that you are using a Bluetooth dongle.  The problem might be with the dongle itself; I would recommend that you borrow a friend's and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

[LEGO's Bluetooth support page](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/bluetooth/default.aspx) has a limited amount of support for Bluetooth errors. It mentions further Bluetooth support can be found in the user guide on:

- Pages 36-45 for NXT 2.0
- Pages 28-37 for NXT 1.0

[Where can I find instruction booklets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/64/132)

You may also get in contact with [LEGO's customer support](http://service.lego.com/en-us/contactus/default.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Your NXT may need to be reset, then the Bluetooth may work. I've found with other devices that sometimes helps. Or maybe you'll need a new NXT. Sadly they are very expensive.

Comment: For such a small problem you shouldn't just buy another NXT, especially if it's the PC or Bluetooth dongle that is causing an error.

Comment: Yes you're right.