# Can the RCX connect to infra-red on a computer?

Tags: compatibility, rcx

Can the RCX connect to a laptop with a IR reciver on it? I want to program my RCX on my computer, But i have no db9 (Lego RCX connecter for 1.0 tower) seriel connecter nor a converter.

Comment: There are converters available for serial to USB, I had to buy one last month for some networking kit.

Comment: And example of one such converter can be seen here: http://www.maplin.co.uk/usb-to-serial-9-pin-male-adaptor-29968

Comment: I've been trying to get an RCX to talk to a serial IR tower using a usb/serial converter - without success. More here: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/rcx-firmware-download-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, the protocol LEGO uses is incompatible with standard IR protocols used in PCs (not even the same frequency, if I remember correctly).

The [NQC FAQ](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nqc/doc/faq.html#irlaptop) has some more explanation on why it's not possible, but their short explanation says it all:

> Quite simply, these protocols are incompatable. *(sic)*

You may have some success using a NXT brick and the [IRLink sensor](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NIL1046), but I'm not sure how far you can go (for example, I'm not even sure you can upload a firmware, and you need to be able to do that).

The easiest way is to stick with the IR tower, and in addition of the serial-to-usb converter mentionned by Zhaph, don't forget there's a USB version of the IR tower available on Bricklink (see [here](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=70887) or [here](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=10759)).