# Where can I download the LEGO RCX 2.0 programming software for Windows 7?

Tags: software, rcx

Can someone point me to an active download location of the RCX 2.0 programming software for Windows 7? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RCX firmware download problem](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/rcx-firmware-download-problem)

Comment: I can conform that Alberto's answer is a good download link; I've been using it myself. But it should be noted that the USB IR tower which comes with the RIS 2.0 kit is not compatible with 64-bit Windows. You'll need an older serial IR tower and a USB-to-Serial converter to program the RCX using 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link for RCX/expansion packs and run the program(s) in compatibility mode: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/718o6673jhpn9/RIS

Comment: Yuck. Mediafire links often present the downloader with fake trojan warnings.