# Batman Arkham Knight Batmobile Instructions

Tags: instructions

Where can I find a set of instructions for the Lego Batman Arkham Knight Batmobile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find instruction booklets?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/64/where-can-i-find-instruction-booklets)

Comment: It would only be a duplicate if the OP was asking for instructions for a released set, but as I looked for it, it seemed to be either a fan model or a video game "character", so likely no official instructions exist.

Answer (score 2):

The author of [this Ideas project](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/82012) might be able to give you a copy of the instructions for his model.